# Как правильно организовать серверный стриминг с grpc и nest.js?

Tags: node.js, rxjs, микросервисы, grpc, nestjs

Необходимо, чтобы клиент мог подписаться на некий "канал", из которого периодически будут сыпаться сообщения.
В рамках текущего стека технологий пытаюсь организовать что-то такое:
прото-файл:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package testtime;

service TimeService {    
    rpc GetTimeStream(Empty) returns (stream TimeStreamResponse);
}

message Empty {
}

message TimeStreamResponse {
    string result = 1;
}
```

контроллер:

```
import { Controller } from '@nestjs/common';
import { GrpcMethod } from '@nestjs/microservices';
import moment from 'moment';
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';

const timeSubject = new Subject<{ result: string }>();
setInterval(() => {
    const result = moment().format('Ленинградское время hh часов mm минут :)');
    timeSubject.next({ result });
}, 5000);

@Controller()
export class TestTimeController {
    @GrpcMethod('testtime.TimeService', 'GetTimeStream')
    public getTimeStream(): Observable<{ result: string }> {
        return timeSubject.asObservable();
    }
}
```

при попытке постучаться на эндпоинт получаю ошибку:

```
/project/node_modules/@nestjs/microservices/server/server-grpc.js:141
             this.transformToObservable(await handler).subscribe(data => callback(null, data), (err) => callback(err));
                                                                         ^
 TypeError: callback is not a function
     at SafeSubscriber._next (/project/node_modules/@nestjs/microservices/server/server-grpc.js:141:73)
     at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (/project/node_modules/rxjs/src/internal/Subscriber.ts:265:10)
     at SafeSubscriber.next (/project/node_modules/rxjs/src/internal/Subscriber.ts:207:14)
     at Subscriber._next (/project/node_modules/rxjs/src/internal/Subscriber.ts:139:22)
     at Subscriber.next (/project/node_modules/rxjs/src/internal/Subscriber.ts:99:12)
     at CatchSubscriber.Subscriber._next (/project/node_modules/rxjs/src/internal/Subscriber.ts:139:22)
     at CatchSubscriber.Subscriber.next (/project/node_modules/rxjs/src/internal/Subscriber.ts:99:12)
     at TapSubscriber._next (/project/node_modules/rxjs/src/internal/operators/tap.ts:125:22)
     at TapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (/project/node_modules/rxjs/src/internal/Subscriber.ts:99:12)
     at MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext (/project/node_modules/rxjs/src/internal/operators/mergeMap.ts:162:22)
     at SimpleInnerSubscriber._next (/project/node_modules/rxjs/src/internal/innerSubscribe.ts:30:17)
     at SimpleInnerSubscriber.Subscriber.next (/project/node_modules/rxjs/src/internal/Subscriber.ts:99:12)
     at MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext (/project/node_modules/rxjs/src/internal/operators/mergeMap.ts:162:22)
     at SimpleInnerSubscriber._next (/project/node_modules/rxjs/src/internal/innerSubscribe.ts:30:17)
     at SimpleInnerSubscriber.Subscriber.next (/project/node_modules/rxjs/src/internal/Subscriber.ts:99:12)
     at SwitchMapSubscriber.notifyNext (/project/node_modules/rxjs/src/internal/operators/switchMap.ts:166:24)
```

что я делаю не так?

Comment: Проблема оказалась в том, что пакеты из @opentelemetry патчат парсинг прото файлов.
Решение проблемы к сожалению привести не могу.

Answer (score 1):

Смотри,  что у тебя в скомпилированных в js прото. Nest ожидает параметром функцию callback, а у тебя что-то  другое (вероятно, observable)